# I made a nodejs express server that connects to a mongo database on mlab. How do I connect CRUD functionality to this server from my React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I built one nodejs app that uses express routing to connect to a mongodb on mlab that listens on a local port.
I built a React app with nodejs that is listening on another port.

How can I have the React app read and write documents to the database? Any tutorials or guides?

Comment: There are many,many tutorials on using node and mongo and react. Google MERN apps.

Comment: Thanks @Pal! Specifically I want to learn how I can merge the two nodejs apps into one working application if possible. Right now the React app using react-router-dom and not express so I'm not sure how I would instantiate a connection to the database within the react app.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line "proxy":"http://localhost:YOUR_SERVER_PORT" to package.json file of react app
This helps react can make Api call to the express app using the same domain
But you need config a route in express to act as an end point for Api call, ex. /api 
Then on server you response to requests to /api routes
Of course you have to config your react app and express app to listen to two different ports, ex. 3000 for react and 4000 for express